# Ao listar tópicos, eu devo usar alguma pontuação?

Tags: pontuação

No meio de um texto, se eu tenho um tópico de características de um produto, como o abaixo mostrado, qual a forma correta de pontuar? Não sei se há alguma diferença, mas gostaria de saber em relação ao português europeu.

**Exemplo:**

> **O que os especialistas dizem**
>
> Um berço é um ótimo complemento para carrinhos, mas tem uma janela de uso bastante limitada e é outra coisa para guardar quando os dias de recém-nascido acabarem. O Mixx resolve isso com uma combinação de assento e berço; basta colocar o assento em uma posição reclinada completamente plana e dobrar o apoio para os pés para criar um berço aconchegante perfeito.
>
> **O que vale a pena considerar**
>
> É um pouco volumoso quando dobrado.
>
> **Características:**
>
> - Idade recomendada: até os 03 anos
> - Cesto grande
> - Capa de chuva incluída
> - Tamanho fechado: 58 x 51 x 48 cm
> - Peso: 14 kg
> - Limite de peso: 17 kg
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há norma consolidada, quer em pt-br, quer em pt-pt (ver, e.g., esta [resposta do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/elementos-de-uma-enumeracao-uso-de-maiusculas-e-pontuacao/33207)) e as três possibilidade mencionadas na pergunta (sem pontuação, com ponto e vírgula, com ponto) são aceitáveis. Assim, talvez o ponto mais importante seja manter coerência dentro de uma mesma publicação/texto.

Mas há regras e tradições, além de normas específicas de uma dada área ou publicação.
Por exemplo, se pode preferir, quando os itens são **curtos** (e, certamente, quando *inline*, i.e., incorporados ao longo do texto) iniciais minúsculas e separação por vírgula ou ponto e vírgula; e, para itens mais **extensos**, iniciais maiúsculas e separação por pontos. Estes e outros critérios são descritos em mais detalhes, por exemplo, no [Manual do Editorial do IPEA](https://www.ipea.gov.br/sites/en-GB/manualeditorial/padroes-editoriais/padronizacoes-textuais/enumeracoes). Por esse critério, o exemplo da pergunta faria uso de minúsculas e do ponto e vírgula.

No caso de uma listagem online, se poderia argumentar que o estilo tipográfico dominante atual favorece a listagem "mais limpa", sem pontuação.

Answer (score 2):

No pt-br, há dois jeitos de listar.

Se você estiver fazendo uma lista informal (para passar para um amigo, uma lista de compra, etc...), você pode deixar sem pontuação.

Entretanto, se for uma lista formal, você deve usar ponto e vírgula. No último tópico da lista, você adiciona um ponto final.

Como não é muito comum fazer listas para situações formais, normalmente todas as listas estão sem pontuação, mas é gramaticalmente correto usar com ponto e vírgula e ponto.

Exemplo de lista formal:

**Lista de materiais para 2021**

- Borracha;
- Lápis;
- Canetas;
- Cadernos e etc.

Exemplo de lista informal:

**Lista de compras**

- Maçã
- Banana
- Uva
- Morango
- Pão francês
- Tangerina
- Biscoito e etc.

OBS: O "etc" está com ponto final, pois é uma abreviação. Se sua lista acabar ali, pode deixar sem ponto final.

Sendo assim, das três opções que dera, só são corretas a A e a B.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigada!