# Qual pontuação correta em uma lista descritiva com tópicos longos dentro de um texto

Tags: português-brasileiro, pontuação, norma-culta

Dentro de um texto de minha autoria, uma tese de doutorado, preciso construir uma parte explicativa de alguns temas. Tenho dúvidas quanto a forma culta e correta em produzir esta estrutura textual, minhas principais questões são.

1. Como dar início a lista de tópicos, a frase que dá a abertura deve estar isolada em um parágrafo ou dentro de um parágrafo maior?
2. Como devo terminar esta frase de transição, uso ponto final (.), dois pontos (:) ou nada?
3. Qual o espaçamento entre a frase de transição e o início da lista de tópicos?
4. Nos tópicos, que elemento devo utilizar para separar o item, e a explicação, um ponto (.), dois-pontos (:), vírgula (,), hífem (-), espaco ( ), algum outra coisa?
5. Qual a pontuação a ser utilizada no fim de cada item, ponto (.), vírgula (,), ponto-virgula (;), nada ( ), alguma outra coisa?

Existe outras recomendações que eu não explicitei para este caso, esta é uma construção válida em textos formais em lingua portuguesa?

Há uma questão aqui no SE sobre o tópico ([Ao listar tópicos, eu devo usar alguma pontuação?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8240/ao-listar-t%C3%B3picos-eu-devo-usar-alguma-pontua%C3%A7%C3%A3o) ), mas ela não se encaixa exatamente na minha questão por algumas razões: a. os elementos da lista são bem menores; b. utiliza "bullets" e não palavras descritivas; e c. não há um consenso ali de qualquer forma.

Abaixo, na imagem abaixo (que parece a continuação do texto), segue um exemplo de um caso concreto.

[image: Exemplo de tópicos descritivos]